# Writing to log file inside a C# class that is invoked by an async Javascript function causes "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: javascript, c#, async-await

This is asking for a lot, I know, but I can't really explain it better than the actual code.

The short, short version of the code is this:

```
GetAsync(endpoint1.ashx).then() 

    --> GetAsync(FPR_Attachments.ashx).then() 
    
        --> FileAttachments.cs 
        
            -->  Log.Write() 
            
                --> "500 Internal Server Error"
```

ANY attempt to `Log.Write()` inside the `FileAttachments` class results in "500 Internal Server Error", even though `Log.Write()` works flawlessly everywhere else in the system.

If I just comment out the `Log.Write()`, everything works fine.

Of particular interest is the nested `GetAsync()` inside the `.then()` of the previous `GetAsync()`.

I suspect, possibly, a racing condition?  But each step is done in the .`then()` of the `GetAsync()` calls, so it should be safe, right?

```
// Javascript GetAsync() function:
// *******************************

async function GetAsync(url, dataType) {

    dataType = dataType || "text";

    try {

        let fetched = await fetch(url);

        if (await fetched.status == 200) {

            switch (dataType) {

                case "text": 
                    fetchedData = await fetched.text(); break;

                case "json":
                    fetchedData = await fetched.json(); break;

                case "binary": await fetched.blob; break;

                default: return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    reject("Invalid data type specified");
                });

            }

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(fetchedData); });

        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject("Error Retrieving Remote Data"); });

    }

}

// JavaScript calling GetAsync() to Call C# API Endpoints (multiple nested times)
// ******************************************************************************

GetAsync("API/data/endpoint1.ashx", "json", 
    { 
        arg1: "CODE", 
        arg2: "FKA-001", 
    })

    .then((jsonData) => {

        let tiles = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

            let newTile = element("tile-template").cloneNode(true);

            GetAsync("API/actions/FPR_Attachments.ashx", "json", {
                Request_Id: 9011,
                Request_Condition_Id: 132983,
            })
                .then((files) => {

                    if (files != "") {

                        let fileLinks = "";

                        for (let j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {

                            fileLinks += (files[j].FileName);
                        }

                        newTile.innerHTML = newTile.innerHTML.replace("{{files}}", fileLinks);

                    } else {
                        newTile.innerHTML = newTile.innerHTML.replace("{{files}}", "");
                    }

                    tiles.push(newTile);
                });

        } // for

        tilesLoaded = true;

        let wait = setInterval(() => {

            if (tilesLoaded && tiles.length > 0) {

                for (let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {

                    element("condition-tile-container").appendChild(tiles[i]);

                }
                
            } else {
                element("condition-tile-container").innerHTML = "<div>NO CONDITIONS FOR THIS RECORD</div>";
            }

            clearInterval(wait);
            
        }, 50);
        
    });

            
            
            
            
// C# Generic Handler API Endpoint calling C# Class FileAttachments()
// ******************************************************************

public class FPR_Attachments : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

        string Request_Id = context.Request.Params["Request_ID"];
        string Request_Condition_Id = context.Request.Params["Request_Condition_ID"];
        string Specific_Path = context.Request.Params["Path"];

        string retJSON;

        if (Request_Id != null && Request_Condition_Id != null) {
            fa = new FileAttachments(
                Convert.ToInt16(Request_Id),
                Convert.ToInt16(Request_Condition_Id)
            );
        }


        if (fa != null && fa.Files.Count > 0) {
            retJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fa.Files);
        }
        
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(retJSON);

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}



// C# Class
// *************

public class FileAttachments {

    public List<FPRFile> Files = new List<FPRFile>();

    public FileAttachments(int fprNum, int condition_id) {

        string File_Location = "\\dir\\subdir\\";

        Log.Write("In the FileAttachments Class"); // <--------------------- 500 INTERNAL ERROR

        if (Directory.Exists(File_Location)) {

            string[] x = Directory.GetFiles(File_Location);

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) {
                Files.Add(new FPRFile {
                    FilePath = x[i],
                    FileName = new FileInfo(x[i]).Name,
                    FileDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(x[i]).ToString(),
                    FileSize = new FileInfo(x[i]).Length.ToString()
                });
            }
        }

    }

}

public class FPRFile {
    public string FilePath;
    public string FileName;
    public string FileDate;
    public string FileSize;
}   

// *************************************************
```

Comment: What exception gets thrown?

Comment: There *should* be some kind of exception recorded at the server; that's what a 500 error means.

Comment: The log file simply reports "500":

2022-07-14 19:59:12 10.15.40.88 GET /endpoint1.ashx &Request_Id=9011&Request_Condition_Id=132983 443 domain\UserName 10.15.40.181 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/103.0.5060.114+Safari/537.36 https:// mysite.com/ 500 0 0 843